# Filter for highest numeric value from Results

Tags: realm, atlas-device-sdk

The objective is the get the object from Realm that contains the highest *numeric* value in one of its properties. The object has a persons name (a string) and a person_id (also a string).

```
PersonClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var name = ""
   @objc dynamic var person_id = ""
}
```

the person_id can be a number, string or a combination. For this filter, all strings that do not contain only a number should be ignored. The table may look like this

```
name     person_id
Henry    0000
Leroy    test
Frank    3333
Steve    a123
```

and the result should be

```
Henry 0000
Frank 3333 <- .last or the highest
```

For a simple example, let's take this array

```
let arrayOfWords = ["thing", "1", "stuff", "2"]
```

and some code to get the string "1" and "2".

```
let swiftResults = arrayOfWords.compactMap { Int($0) } //knowing that Int has limitations
swiftResults.forEach { print($0) } //note we can use .last to get the last one
```

While there is solution by getting all Realm objects and then applying a Swift filter, the problem is there could be thousands of persons and as soon as the results object is manipulated as a Swift enumerated object (like an array), it not only breaks the connection with Realm (losing the objects live updating ability) but they are are no longer lazily loaded, taking up memory and possibly overwhelming the device.

Comment: You are looking for the highest numeric value so why the result would be both Henry and Frank? Shouldn't it be only Frank?

Comment: @rs7 Assuming we can get those results, .last would be the 'highest' I didnt specify that in the question - updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since realm queries do not support regex, you'd have to check that no letter is contained in person_id and get the max value using @max.

```
let regexAnythingButDigits = "[^0-9]"
let maxNumericID = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("person_id NOT CONTAINS[c] 'a' person_id NOT CONTAINS[c] 'b' AND ..[all letters in between]... AND person_id NOT CONTAINS[c] 'z' AND person_id.@max", regexAnythingButDigits)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's similar to the solution in the question, however, it will take the live Realm results and cast them to a swift array with that filter `{ Int($0) != nil }` so that won't work - the objects are no longer lazily loaded but it also breaks their connection to Realm. I tried to address that at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Ok. Well, in this case, you'd just have to manually list all the characters except digits and that should do it. Something like "person_id NOT CONTAINS[c] 'a' AND  person_id NOT CONTAINS[c] 'b' ...." and so on. And see how that works for you. I updated my answer again.

Comment: If you test it, I'd be curious to know if it performs well despite the long predicate.

Comment: Thank you and *brilliant*. While the code in your answer isn't valid Realm filter code (NOT, @MAX doesn't work for strings, regex etc) it absolutely lead me down the right path for solution. I am hitting 20,000+ thousand objects with the solution and not finding any real performance issues. I added it as an answer for future readers.

Comment: Glad I was able to help out. You helped a lot on the Realm forum so thank you for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the insight provided in the answer by rs7, here's a coding solution that meets the criteria in the question.

TLDR: we build a compound AND predicate that filters Realm for all strings that have no alpha characters. i.e. get all strings that do not have 'a' AND 'b' AND 'c' etc.

This is important because there could be thousands of objects and while filtering using pure Swift is super simple code-wise, doing that goes around the lazy-loading characteristic of Realm and the entire dataset would need to be loaded into the array for filtering, which could overwhelm the device.

This solution keeps the Realm objects lazy avoiding that issue.

```
let charStringToOmit = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" //the invalid chars
let charsOmitArray = Array(charStringToOmit) //make an array of Char objects
var predicateArray = [NSPredicate]() //the array of predicates

//iterate over the array of char objects
for char in charsOmitArray {
    let c = String(char) //make each char a string
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "!(person_id CONTAINS[cd] %@)", c) //craft a predicate
    predicateArray.append(pred) //append the predicate to the array
}

//craft compound AND predicate
let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray) 

let realm = try! Realm()
let results = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter(compound).sorted(byKeyPath: "person_id")

if let lastPerson = results.last {
    print(lastPerson.person_id)
}
```

I simplified the initial dataset provided for this example and limited it to only have a-z and 0-9 characters but that could be expanded on.